# Node - hackathon starter cannot load static files?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, pug

I followed the instructions in https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter to kickstart a user authentication system. The site runs on localhost and editing the html files modifies the page. However, I want to add and modify some existing css for the page, but it doesn't seem to load any changes I make in the `public` folder.

In app.js, static files are set by:

```
app.use(sass({
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
}));
```

and

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), { maxAge: 31557600000 }));`

when I do `inspect element` on the result page served from localhost, the sources for `localhost:8080` contains the same files with same code, even though I modified these files in the `public` folder in my local directory.

I tried:

- Add a new folder and css file in `public/css` to modify some html element
- Modify the existing main.css file in `public/css`
- deleting the whole public folder
- comment out `link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/main.css')` in `views/partials/layout.pug`, which does change the webpage(took out all styling elements, which makes sense)

I'm suspecting it's loading its public folder from somewhere, but I don't know how and where.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm looking for the same

Maybe what you are looking for is https://github.com/sass/node-sass-middleware as mentioned here: https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter/issues/695